# URL Rewite Module - Exact Url (IIS .Net MVC)

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

I have .net MVC application. We are trying to redirect an old Url to a new Url.

Example:
Old Link https://www.example.com/App/Home/Index
New Link https://www.example.com/Home/Index

I tried to solve the issue using URL Rewrite Module but the application keeps telling me Controller App is not found.

Here is what I have tried:

```
 <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="CARES2" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="https://www.example.com/App/Home/Index" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="https://www.example.com/Home/Index" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                </conditions>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: Mistake 1 in https://halfblood.pro/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to test the rule on my side and found that below rule is working as per your requirement.

```
<rewrite>
   <rules>
      <rule name="old to new" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url="(.*)" />
         <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/app/Home/Index" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/Home/Index" />
      </rule>
   </rules>
</rewrite>
```

**Output:**

[image]

You could try to test with it and modify the rule as per your requirements.